# How do you use Swagger Maven Plugin with an existing project correctly

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I have an existing Jetty project that uses Spring-MVC.
I have now introduced swagger to create a .yaml file with new API spec file (v2 of APIs as I have to write new APIs, leaving existing APIs alone because of legacy reasons).

I have set up the swagger-maven-plugin (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) to generate the models and API interfaces into my src/main folder.

Is this a correct way of doing this or not?

By default it generates these files into the target/auto-generated folder which I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to check-in generated source files, which are generated every time you touch your input-file? This means, you always have a **redundant commit** if you change your input file. But it comes even worst, another developer (not familier with your solution) might think there is java code in a source folder, so he can just make a small change there to fix an issue. It might even work on his local machine. But after pushing into your SCM and an full maven build on the build server, his changes would be gone.

Comment: So am I just supposed to use swagger for documentation? I can’t use swagger to write spec first then use the generated models and interfaces in my project?

Comment: No, check out the delegatePattern option and "contract-first" swagger articles.